# Magento 2 m2e pro installation error

Tags: php, class, magento, magento2, m2e-pro

I try to install m2e pro on magento 2.0.9 by uploading module to the `app/code/..` and then i execute the command

```
magento setup:upgrade
```

just like it says in here: https://docs.m2epro.com/display/eBayMagento2/Installation

Everything seems fine, front-end is working,
however back-end page is blank and returns error

> Class Magento\Framework\EntityManager\MetadataPool does not exist";i:1;s:10391:"#0 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php(44): Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor('Ess\M2ePro\Mode...')

I have tried to clear var/cache and var/generation folders and nothing still get this error....

Answer (score 0):

Try to run other command given in m2e document for static content and compilation.

PHP:

```
magento setup:static-content:deploy;
bin/magento setup:di:compile;
```

I hope it will fix out for you..